# What are some commercial products today that are based on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: commercial-use

Are there commercial products today selling in the market that are based on the Raspberry Pi today? If yes, are they a commercial success?

Comment: You need to define 'commercial'.  Commercial as being available off-the-shelve or commercial as being implemented in a commercial environment?

Answer (score 2):

**One** is pi-top

**Two** is https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/fiveninjas/slice-a-media-player-and-more

**Three** is https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1598272670/meet-otto-the-hackable-gif-camera

**Fourth**  dock2office

Hope it helps!